# WCF Service Reference Interface and Excessive Namespaces in Java Web Service Response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, service-reference

So I am working on an internal project where I am consuming a Java based SOAP Web Service from a WinForm application using a WCF Service Reference interface.  (This is something new for me so I apologize if I not totally using the right terminology, etc.)  I am sending my request over to the service and I am getting a response, although it has taken some hoop jumping to get there.  The format of the response is what is causing me some problems in that it has excessive namespaces and the response size can get large.

I hope someone can point me to a simple solution / setting to reduce the excess.

**A few things that I have no control over:**  The interface is via HTTP (not HTTPS) and security is handled via an App Key/ID mechanism using the a SOAP Security Header and client certificates. The server WSDL does not indicate that WSSE is required in the SOAP Header so the header is being overwritten by the security one prior to the send.

All items below are actual code structure and SOAP request/response format but have been changed to generic items.  Also, the "response" is greatly reduced in size.  With the right request parameters, a response is over 64k in length.

The SoapUI Request 1 example built with the WSDL load looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pric="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing" xmlns:ns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pric: PricingRequest majorVersion="2" minorVersion="1">
         <pric:version>?</pric:version>
         <pric:timestamp>?</pric:timestamp>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <pric:acctType>
            <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
            <pric:customerNbr>?</pric: customerNbr >
            <pric:accountNbr>?</pric:accountNbr>
         </pric: acctType >
         <!--1 to 3 repetitions:-->
         <pric:system>?</pric: system >
         <pric:source>?</pric:source>
         <pric:searchItems>
            <pric:purchaseDate>?</pric: purchaseDate >
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <pric:service>
               <ns:system>?</ns:system>
               <ns:serviceType>?</ns:serviceType>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:serviceDesc>?</ns:serviceDesc>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:billingType>?</ns:billingType>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:effectiveDate>?</ns:effectiveDate>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:expirationDate>?</ns:expirationDate>
               <!--Optional:-->
            </pric:service>
         </pric: searchItems >
      </pric: PricingRequest >
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The app.config Service Model - I added the maxReceivedMessageSize in order to handle the large responses:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="PricingServiceSoap11" maxReceivedMessageSize="256000" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://pricing-websvc.example.com:60000/PricingService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PricingServiceSoap11"
            contract="pricingSvcRef.PricingService" name="PricingServiceSoap11" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Code to consume service:

```
pricingSvcRef.PricingClient pricing = new pricingSvcRef.PricingClient();

var reqInfo = new InspectorBehavior();
pricing.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(reqInfo);

pricingSvcRef.PricingRequest request = new pricingSvcRef.PricingRequest();

request.majorVersion = 2;
request.minorVersion = 1;
request.version = pricingSvcRef.PricingRequestVersion.Ver1;
request.timestamp = DateTime.Now;

request.acctType = new pricingSvcRef.PricingRequestAcctType[1];
request.acctType[0] = new pricingSvcRef.GetPricingRequestAcctype();
request.acctType[0].Item = txtAcctNo.Text.Trim();

request.system = "Pricing";
request.source = "MyApp";

List<pricingSvcRef.pricingService> svcList = new List<pricingSvcRef.pricingService>();

svcList.Add(
        new pricingSvcRef.pricingService
        {
            system = txtSystem.Text.Trim(),
            serviceType = Convert.ToInt32(txServiceType.Text.Trim(),
            serviceDesc = txtService.Text.Trim(),
            billingType = Convert.ToInt32(txBillingType.Text.Trim(),
            effectiveDate = dateEffective.Value,
            expirationDate = dateExpiration.Value
        });

pricingSvcRef.PricingRequestSearchItems srchItems = new pricingSvcRef.PricingRequestSearchItems
{
    purchaseDate = DateTime.Now;
    service = svcList.ToArray(),
};

request.searchItems = srchItems;

pricingSvcRef.PricingResponse response = null;

try
{
    response = eddSvcRef.GetPricing(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string msg = "Msg: " + ex.Message;

    if ((ex.InnerException != null) && (ex.InnerException.Message.Trim().Length > 0))
        msg = msg + "\r\n\r\nInner Msg: " + ex.InnerException.Message.Trim();

    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

SOAP Request that is generated:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>v1:APP1234567:SfPLRHKdXWWqW7mdOdk+gTABVo+y4VZR7UqLHWibVD73jaI0IL9FT4PMgAVAxGsa83P/aon61GuS+IZnuVjRHR4hJgyMuCvtI07QtNaSdwEyw9Lw/Iewm+098fkMYK2pflV7w6hn0U2A9/wzuQS/vfWe53vhGSX1zfhuo6AygKA=:APP1234567</wsse:Username>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PricingRequest majorVersion="2" minorVersion="1" xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing">
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <timestamp>2019-03-25T09:46:26.7337264-05:00</timestamp>
      <acctType>
        <accountNbr>123456789</accountNbr>
      </acctType>
      <system>Pricing</system>
      <source>MyApp</source>
      <searchItems>
        <purchaseDate>2019-03-25</purchaseDate>
        <service>
          <system xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">MyPricing</system>
          <serviceType xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">1000</serviceType>
          <serviceDesc xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">Service Description</serviceDesc>
          <billingType xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">1234</billingType>
          <effectiveDate xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">2019-01-01</effectiveDate>
          <expirationDate xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">2019-12-31</expirationDate>
        </service>
      </searchItems>
    </PricingRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response in application:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <PricingResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing">
      <pricingContainer xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">
        <version xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">1.0.0</version>
        <timestamp xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">2019-03-25T14:46:28.876Z</timestamp>
        <source xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">MyApp</source>
        <status xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">
          <code xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">0000</code>
          <description xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">SUCCESS</description>
        </status>
        <acctType xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">
          <accountNbr xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">123456789</accountNbr>
        </acctType>
        <system xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">Pricing</system>
        <serviceDetail xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">
          <valid xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">Y</valid>
          <system xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">MyPricing</system>
          <serviceType xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">1000</serviceType>
          <serviceDesc xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">Service Description</serviceDesc>
          <billingType xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">1234</billingType>
          <effectiveDate xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">2019-01-01</effectiveDate>
          <expirationDate xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">2019-12-31</expirationDate>
          <pricingRate xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/system/pricing/shared/3.1.1">100</pricingRate>
        </serviceDetail>
      </pricingContainer>
    </PricingResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So even though namespaces are returning as part of the **PricingResponse** element, they are also on each child item below that.

**UPDATE:** I thought SoapUI responses were coming back w/o the excessive namespace items on each element but I have now determined using Wireshark and SoapUI Raw display that this not the case.

Is there anyway to request from the WCF Interface to the Java Web Service that the response uses namespace prefixes rather than having a namespace on almost every response element?  Obviously I am going to keep digging at it but any help / guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: SoapUI might be cleaning somethings up before it displays them.  Started up Wireshark and was looking at the returns for both the application and the SoapUI sends and both have the extra namespaces on the various child elements.  However, SoapUI is not showing them.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't control namespace serialization of the server from the client side. You'll have to request the party that hosts the service to do something about it.